# backup da database

Tags: c#, sql, servidor, backup

Olhei em alguns tutoriais aqui no site, mas não achei um que se encaixa-se no que procuro, então segui esse tutorial
[Backup & Restore Sql Server database in C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fl7PQ7vpCY)

ele tem até um link nos comentários com os codes já prontos, mas quando clico pra criar o backup da DB aparece esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se faz diferença, não uso o Sql Server Management, uso direto no Visual Studio 2010, alguém sabe me dizer como resolvo o problema?

PS1:

```
        private void btn_criar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string database = con.Database.ToString();
        try
        {
            if (path_criar.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter backup file location");
            }
            else
            {
                string cmd = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + database + "] TO DISK='" + path_criar.Text + "\\" + "database" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, con))
                {
                    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("database backup done successefully");
                    btn_criar.Enabled = false;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

a parte da linha 54 é essa `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

PS2: descobri que se eu clicar em efetuar o backup novamente logo após fechar o erro, ele efetua o backup ou restaura dependendo do que eu escolher, então eu "engembrei", coloquei no "catch" um btn_criar.PerformClick(); pra ele clicar o botão novamente ao invés do erro aparecer, mas gostaria de resolver o problema pois não sei que problemas podem acontecer futuramente (e sim, já testei e o backup funciona)

Comment: Henrique seja bem-vindo a comunidade, te recomendo a fazer o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como funciona a comunidade, primeiramente tente fazer algo, depois faça a pergunta expondo sua dúvida e ou problema.

Comment: O primeiro erro que relatado é um alias mal declarado, onde parece gerar uma sequencia de erros. Henrique posta o código do seu backup.cs, especificamente área do método que acerca a linha 54.

Answer (score 0):

Em um Server é comum usar a biblioteca SMO para fazer um backup ou restairação. SMO | SQL Server Management Objects contém inúmeras classes que facilitada e muito o gerenciamento de um banco de maneira programática. Caso tenha interesse veja aqui: [Documentação SMO Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo)

Elaborei um exemplo bem sim mais e eficaz para fazer um backup de uma DB LOCAL.

Após criar um projeto, adicionei um banco .mdf ao projeto e deixei com nome padrão Database1.mdf, adicionei uma nova consulta, criei uma tabela e logo partir para mesma sintaxe usada por vc: `BACKUP DATABASE - TO DISK=''`. veja a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui me deparei com dois problemas:

- Propriedade `Conexao.Database` me retornando `null`;
- DataTime.Now.ToString() gerando erro de sintaxe;

Note que tenho uma string de nome query comentada que foi minha primeira tentativa, onde me deparei com os 2 problemas.

A solução que encontrei foi usar o Application.StartupPath, para me retornar o caminho até a db adicionando seu nome logo em seguida. o 2 problema que afetava a sintaxe eram os separadores de data e hora utilizados no formato de retorno.

```
string query = $"BACKUP DATABASE [{Application.StartupPath}\\DATABASE1.MDF] TO DISK ='{textBox1.Text}\\Database1_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")}.bak'";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que funcionou perfeitamente, na imagem acima na tela da pasta desktop tenho 3 backup, apesar de 2 estarem um pouco mais acima. a cada click gera um novo, não temo como sobrepor pois o `DateTime` nunca ira retornar o msm nanossegundo.